# Is using data-val="true" the right approach , to force the required validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CheckUserPermision", "SecurityRole", 
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "progress2",
    UpdateTargetId = "userSecurityRole"
}))
{


  <div>
    <span class="f">User Name </span> 
        <input  name="username" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required= "Please enter a value." data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "SecurityGroup")"  /> 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="username" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

</div>
```

currently the users will not be able to do a search unless they enter text inside the "User name" field. but my question is weather using `data-val="true`" the right approach to force Required field validation ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Just use a ViewModel for this.

```
public class SearchNameViewModel
{   
   [Required]
   public string UserName { get;set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@model SearchNameViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CheckUserPermision", "SecurityRole", 
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "get",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "progress2",
    UpdateTargetId = "userSecurityRole"
}))
{


  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName,
     new { data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete", "SecurityGroup") })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)
</div>
```

Comment: i know that this will work also, but what is wrong with my approach ? thanks

Comment: I just think that this is more flexible. Like in the future if you want to add more validations or you want to add properties, you can have them all in one place and have them strongly typed to the view. Also the validation is easily applied to the view, I think the code it produces looks cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

One is client-side validation, the other is server side.  Proper secure coding standards would have you use both.  Server side validation (view model data annotation) is more secure, however client side validation allows you to catch the problem before the request is sent.

Comment: Client-side validation is very convenient and improves the user experience greatly. Server-side validation is absolutely a must as client-side validation cannot be trusted. So I agree, both together is best.